# Getting error while defining Toast. Can we mix .android and .androidx libraries together?

Tags: android, android-toast

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

```
public open fun makeText(context: Context!, text: CharSequence!, duration: Int): 
Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
public open fun makeText(context: Context!, resId: Int, duration: Int): Toast! defined in android.widget.Toast
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `makeText()` function with wrong arguments.
if you have overloaded functions for same amount of arguments, but call it with wrong type arguments, you'll have this error. In this situation there is 2 function with 3 arguments.